# Swift Singleton

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I'm currently working on a Shopify Application that uses their [mobile buy sdk](https://docs.shopify.com/mobile-buy-sdk/ios), and I'm trying to save the cart using a Singleton in Swift. I have a Singleton class that's set up like so:

```
class Singleton {

   static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

   init() {
     var cart = BUYCart()
     println(cart)
   }
}
```

When it gets initialized, it prints the BUYCart in the console. The problem is I'm trying to access the saved cart in a controller like so:

```
  println(Singleton.sharedInstance.cart.lineItems)
```

I get the following error:

```
 Singleton does not have member named 'cart'
```

Answer (score 9):

You should declare the variable at instance level. In your code its declared inside the constructor, so you can only access it inside the constructor. Not from outside the class like you are doing in your code.

```
class Singleton {

   static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
   var cart = BUYCart()

   init() {
     println(cart)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This isn't necessarily a direct response to your question, so downvote away. But if you want this to be a singleton, make the `init` method `private` so that you can really, truly, only create one instance of it:

```
class Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    var cart = BUYCart()

    private init() {
        println(cart)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, my upvote you shall receive. (Theoretically it's still possible to instantiate instances anywhere in the same file, which is much better than in the whole module though)

Answer (score 0):

#### Notes

1. According to the Swift's API guidelines, `sharedInstance` should be `shared`.
2. Making the original `init` method prevents it from accidentally initialize from outside.
3. `println` is `print` since a long time now.
4. Since **Swift 5.2**, You can point to the type with `Self`. So just one line could create a singleton for almost any type:

```
static let shared = Self()
```

---

#### Finally

It would be like:

```
class SomeTypeWithASingletonInstance {
    static let shared = Self()
    private init() { print(cart) }
}
```